# jquery: how to traverse upwards incrementally (adding parent()) via function?

Tags: jquery

this code below selects all the given children from the parent.

```
$(this).parent().find(this.attr("tagName").toLowerCase())
```

however, i dont know how to traverse upwards with the parent(). i would require a function that would automatically keep adding .parent() each time the function is called.

For example, i call function once and it returns
`$(this).parent().find(this.attr("tagName").toLowerCase())`

I call the function for second time again and it returns
`$(this).parent().parent().find(this.attr("tagName").toLowerCase())`

Third time,
`$(this).parent().parent().parent().find(this.attr("tagName").toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p:eq(0)').parents().each(function() {
    var el = $(this).find( $(this).attr('tagName').toLowerCase() );
    if ( el.length ) {
        console.log(el);
    }
});
```

Comment: im not sure what this does....but what i meant was call a function which will return $(this).parent().find(this.attr("tagName").toLowerCase()). call it again and it will return $(this).parent().parent().find(this.attr("tagName").toLowerCase())

Comment: Well, if you have Firebug you can copy my code paste it in and pretty much see what it does, but it basically loops through all the parent elements of the initial node and finds similar node name descendants and logs them, you can do what you want with the `el` variable.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has a function equivalent to the `find` which works upwards rather than downwards called  `closest` added in jQuery 1.3

- http://api.jquery.com/closest/

For example

```
$(this).parent().closest(this.attr("tagName").toLowerCase())
```